# React hot toast useState not exported from react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hot-toast

im trying to use react-hot-toast in a nextjs proyect but when i import it to any file i get this error

error - ./node_modules/react-hot-toast/dist/index.mjs
Attempted import error: 'useState' is not exported from 'react' (imported as 'j').

this is the file i tried to import it in

```
'use client';

import { Icons } from '@/components/Icons';
import { cn } from '@/lib/utils';
import * as React from 'react';
import hotToast, { Toaster as HotToaster } from 'react-hot-toast';

export const Toaster = HotToaster;
```

them use it in this file

```
import '@/styles/globals.css';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import { cn } from '@/lib/utils';
import Providers from '@/components/Providers';
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar';
import { Toaster } from '@/components/ui/toast';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html
      lang='en'
      className={cn('bg-white text-slate-900 antialiased', inter.className)}
    >
      <body className='min-h-screen bg-slate-50 dark:bg-slate-900 antialiased'>
        <Providers>
          <Toaster position='bottom-right' />
          {/* @ts-expect-error Server Component */}
          <Navbar />
          {children}
        </Providers>
        <div className='h-40 md:hidden' />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue has something to do with code being run on server components in Nextjs. I had a similar issue where another library (Tanstack Table) couldn't import useState from react when I was on a server component or rendering a server component from a client component. Try changing your component tree so that you don't have the client Toaster as a parent to the server Navbar.